# Need help in python code for DNA base pair complementary

Tags: python

I am trying to run the code for complementary DNA base pairs but having a problem.
the code is below please let me know what is the problem with the code. i am really new in programming and python

```
file = open("My_strDNA.txt", "r")
print(file.read())

def base():
    for base in file:
        if base=="T":
            base="A"
        elif base=="A":
            base="T"
        elif base=="C":
            base="G"
        elif base=="G":
            base="C"
        elif base=="3":
            base="5"
        elif base=="5":
            base="3"
print(base)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the problem you're facing and what you're trying to achieve? It's not evident from the code provided.

Comment: I am having this <function base at 0x7fc3cce770d0> message on the terminal after executing the code, I am not able to understand what does it mean, I am really new in python, I have a text file with the information of DNA base-pair sequence and I want its complementary sequence as you can see in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to execute the function. At the moment you are simply printing the reference to it.

Change your last line to `print(base())`

```
file = open("My_strDNA.txt", "r")
print(file.read())

def base():
    for base in file:
        if base=="T":
            base="A"
        elif base=="A":
            base="T"
        elif base=="C":
            base="G"
        elif base=="G":
            base="C"
        elif base=="3":
            base="5"
        elif base=="5":
            base="3"
        print(base)
base()
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it worked but it didn't change the sequence in complementary, can please see if there is any problem in looping?

Comment: your print statement is outside the loop, hence it is only returning the last `base`.

Comment: Can you please specify where this statement should be in the code?, I will be really thankful to you

Comment: code is executing but still didn't change the complementry